# Splitting multiple strings using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

```
[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines
[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines
```

I want to get Delta-1234 and United-1345 in the first case and just Delta-1234 in the second. Is it possible using findall?

Comment: I don't see how findall() could do it because you don't want the square brackets in the resulting list. So the square brackets can't be in the pattern.  In @CertainPerformances answer you'd still have to split on commas and remove the square brackets.

Comment: oops, just split on the commas for @CertainPerformace - I missed that the square brackets are outside the capture group.  That is assuming you want an actual list of flight-like things, e.g. a=[ 'Delta-1234', 'United-1345' ] instead of a list with a single csv-string like b=[ 'Delta-1234, United-1345' ].  Note len(a) == 2 while len(b) == 1.

Comment: @jgreve That's what I just i.e. len(b) == 2. But I wanted to see if its possible with just one regex rather than doing a split later. I actually want something like `[('Delta', '1234'), ('United', ''1345)]` that's why I thought findall may be a good option!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need regular expressions? You can just find elements between the brackets `[` and `]`

```
x = lambda s: s[s.index('['):s.index("]")+1]

string1 = "[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines"
string2 = "[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines"

print(x(string1))
print(x(string2))
```

outputs

```
[Delta-1234, United-1345]
[Delta-1234]
```

Comment: I just wanted a list as an output, I am not sure if this lamba gives me a list, but rather a string,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular expression, just match `[`, and then (greedily) capture repeated non-`]`s:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\[([^\]]+)")
>>> re.findall(regex, "[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines")
['Delta-1234, United-1345']
>>> re.findall(regex, "[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines")
['Delta-1234']
```

Or use lookbehind

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\[)[^\]]+")
>>> re.findall(regex, "[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines")
['Delta-1234, United-1345']
>>> re.findall(regex, "[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines")
['Delta-1234']
```

Comment: So the first out is a list of one item: ['Delta-1234, United-1345']. Can this be split to a list of two items using the regex?

Comment: If you want more than one group, then if you want to use `findall`, the returned value will have to be a list of tuples, there's no way around that. You can use `r"\[(\S+)(?:, (\S+))?\]"` to capture the first, or the first and second airline code.

Comment: The issue is that the regex wouldn't work if the string becomes `[Delta-1234, United-1345, Spirit-8778] Testing different airlines`. My point being, the airlines and their code can vary and can be more than 1.

Comment: If you want to use `findall` for this, then you'll need a separate capturing group for each substring. (Repeating a captured group, eg `\[(\S+)(?:, (\S+))*\`, doesn't work because only the last match for the second group would be retained in the result.) While you *could* manually repeat groups like `r"\[(\S+)(?:, (\S+))?(?:, (\S+))?\]"` (repeat the groups as much as you need), that's pretty messy. Better to keep code DRY and branch out from pure `re.findall`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this using regex is:

```
import re

str1 = "[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines"
str2 = "[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines"

regex_pattern = r"[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]"

print(re.match(regex_pattern, str1).groups()[0])
print(re.match(regex_pattern, str2).groups()[0])
```

It will print

```
Delta-1234, United-1345
Delta-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
s='''\
[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines
[Delta-1234] Testing different airlines'''
```

You can do:

```
>>> [e.split(', ') for e in re.findall(r'\[([^]]+)\]', s)]
[['Delta-1234', 'United-1345'], ['Delta-1234']]
```

Comment: If I were to use just `[Delta-1234, United-1345] Testing different airlines`, then `re.findall(r'\[([^]]+)\]', s` only creates one value in the list: `['Delta-1234, United-1345']`. However, I am looking for two values in the list. Is that possible?

Comment: It is returning a list of lists. The string you state is being split correctly into a two element list inside another list.

Comment: You might try changing the `e.split(', ')` to `e.split(',')` (ie, no space after the comma). Or split with a regex.